# Why Django DecimalField let me store Float or string?

Tags: python, django, floating-point, decimal

I don't understand the behaviour of [Django DecimalField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#decimalfield).

It's defined as:

> A fixed-precision decimal number, represented in Python by a Decimal instance.

However, with the following model:

```
class Article(models.Model)
    unit_price = DecimalField(max_digits=9, decimal_places=2)
```

I can create an article in at least 3 ways:

```
article = Article.objects.create(unit_price="2.3")
type(article.unit_price)
>>> str

article = Article.objects.create(unit_price=2.3)
type(article.unit_price)
>>> float

article = Article.objects.create(unit_price=Decimal('2.3'))
type(article.unit_price)
>>> decimal.Decimal
```

Why Django DecimalField is able to return something else than Decimal type?

What would be the best way to ensure my app never deals with floats for prices?

Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Why Django DecimalField is able to return something else than Decimal
>   type?

This is because Django is permissive during model creation and allows you to input any type to these fields without erroring out if what you input can be coerced to the specified type.

After inserting it in the database it gets the right type. You can verify this using `refresh_from_db()`:

```
article = Article.objects.create(unit_price="2.3")
type(article.unit_price)
>>> str
article.refresh_from_db()
type(article.unit_price)
>>> decimal.Decimal
```

> What would be the best way to ensure my app never deals with floats
>   for prices?

The only way to ensure this is to coerce any price input to `decimal.Decimal` as soon as you know it's a price amount.

Answer (score 3):

Well, the `decimal.Decimal` subtype, is itself a `float` in nature, that's why it is accepted in your model. The decimal.Decimal type provides further arithmetic accuracy to the float type.

As explained in the decimal type [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html), the operation:

```
0.1 + 0.1 + 0.1 - 0.3
```

using decimal.Decimal gives exactly `0`, as in the float type gives a number close to zero:

```
5.5511151231257827e-017
```

In the end, `decimal.Decimal` numbers can represent exactly.

> A decimal number is immutable. It has a sign, coefficient digits, and
>   an exponent. To preserve significance, the coefficient digits do not
>   truncate trailing zeros. Decimals also include special values such as
>   Infinity, -Infinity, and NaN. The standard also differentiates -0 from
>   +0.

In order to have explicit decimals in your application you must be also explicit and pay attention to decimal transformations, every db in/out or serialization operations using the cast to `decimal.Decimal`.

To dig further on how the floating point operations have a long story in the background, you can visit this [Decimal Arithmetic Specification](http://speleotrove.com/decimal/)

Comment: I think the statement "the decimal.Decimal subtype, is itself a float in nature" is misleading. A Decimal is more similar to an int than to a float. It's a fixed point integer, which is basically an integer with a defined, fixed decimal point.

A float is composed by a mantissa and exponent.

Ints and Decimals don't have the concept of an exponent. That's why they are more accurate for the same number of bits. Although their dynamic range is of course lower.